# Windows process dependences

Tags: windows, visual-studio, taskmanager

I have windows application that use DLL. When I close the application it is still process in task manager because of the DLL isn't unloaded from memory for some reason. I can kill application process from Task manager but I'd like to understand the reason why DLL wasn't unloaded automatically.

Note. I have sources of application (C#) and DLL (Visual C++) in VS 2010 and I can debug it. But I don't know how to find dependences. May be there are some tools or debugging abilities?

Comment: You've got this backwards. The DLLs aren't unloaded from memory, because the process didn't terminate. It's not the other way around, i.e. failure to unload a DLL will not keep a process from terminating. Unless the process is explicitly waiting for DLLs to unload. You can debug this by breaking into the process and looking at the call stacks of all threads to find out, why the process won't terminate.

Comment: Best guess: one of the DllMain functions is deadlocking, probably because of a global destructor that does something it shouldn't.  As IInspectable says, breaking into the process with a debugger should show you what's happening.